# Web2lead redirects to a page which makes you click

Tags: web2lead

After submitting a Web2Lead form which has the following code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="thanks.html" id="retURL" name="retURL">
```

I'm taken to a page which asks me to click before going to that page, instead of simply redirecting straight to that page. **(Screenshot below)**

How do I skip the click and redirect straight away?

[image]

Comment: It should be automatic... might be a browser security option? Have you tried another browser?

Answer (score 4):

After much searching, I found the answer. If the return URL is on a different domain to the current domain, it will ask the user to click first:

> The redirect page is being displayed due to some security measures
>   that Salesforce has in place with our web to lead infrastructure.  In
>   cases when a GET method is utilized and the referring URL (as
>   specified in HTTP headers) cannot be matched to the return URL,
>   Salesforce will introduce a new page notifying the Leads that they are
>   being redirected to a different URL. This will allow them to take the
>   necessary action to cancel that redirect. The workaround for this is
>   to change the GET method to POST or use HTTP headers to specify the
>   retURL.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers#!/feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&id=90630000000gmagAAA

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need todo anything, just change the value param in the retUrl

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<form>
  <input type=hidden name="oid" value="(IDgenerated)">
  <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.google.com">
  <label for="first_name">FirstName</label><input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="last_name">LastName</label><input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="email">Email</label><input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="company">Company</label><input id="company" maxlength="40" name="company" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="city">City</label><input id="city" maxlength="40" name="city" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <label for="state">State/Provincia</label><input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" /><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```